# How to use python library's logger message to trigger a process in my own code?

Tags: python-3.x, exception, python-logging

I am using a library that instead of raising an exception just sends a logger message when my request is not processed. This part of the method looks like this:

```
if result is None:
    _logger.error("Request timed out")
```

The application I am working on cannot just print out the message, I have to actively interrupt/change the algorithm in case the API the library leverages is down. I also do not own the library and cannot modify it to raise an exception.
Is there a way I could use the logger.error message to trigger an actual exception in my own code?

I guess I could to create a child class based on logging.Manager object which would raise an exception if the logger content is "Request timed out", but I am not sure how to redirect the logger's output into this one if it is not initiated in my own file but a called library.